# Creación de gráficos con Highcharts y Highstock

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, highcharts

Estoy creando un gráfico con las librerías de `highchart` y `highstock`.

La librería `highchart` funciona perfecto y ya puedo hacer muchas modificaciones, pero al momento de usar la librería de `highstock` genera un error y no puedo visualizarla:

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
namespace GraficaPrueba
{
    public partial class Grafica : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlConnection cn;
        SqlCommand cmd;
        SqlDataReader dr;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Grafica_Chart();
        }

        public byte[] selectAlarmas(int idPAciente)
        {
            try
            {
                cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=JAVIERCASASUC;Initial Catalog=FUCS;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=pasante1;Password=sebastian1");
                cn.Open();
                Console.Write("conectado bien");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.Write("no se conecto" + e);
            }
            byte[] Datos = null;
            List<int> numeros = new List<int>();
            try
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand("Select ECG1 From dbo.Alarm where PatientiID=" + idPAciente + ";", cn);
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.Write("No se puede Consultar bien " + e.ToString());
            }
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    if (!dr.IsDBNull(0))
                    {
                        Datos = (byte[])dr.GetValue(0);
                        for (int i = 0; i < Datos.Length; i++)
                        {
                            numeros.Add(Datos[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return Datos;
        }

        protected void Grafica_Chart()
        {
            byte[] Datos = null;
            List<int> graficoY = new List<int>();
            Datos = selectAlarmas(104);
            Object[] chartValues = new Object[Datos.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < Datos.Length; i++)
            {
                chartValues[i] = Datos[i];
            }
            // Declare the HighCharts object    
           // DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts chart = new DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts("StockChart")
              DotNet.Highstock.Highstock chart = new DotNet.Highstock.Highstock("Chart")
                        .InitChart(new Chart
                        {
                            Type = ChartTypes.Line,
                            ZoomType = ZoomTypes.X,
                            Width = 900,
                            Height = 300
                            //DefaultSeriesType = ChartTypes.Line,
                            //ZoomType = ZoomTypes.X,
                            //SpacingRight = 20
                        })
                        .SetTitle(new Title
                        {
                            Text = ""
                        })
                        .SetPlotOptions(new PlotOptions {
                            Line = new PlotOptionsLine
                            {
                                EnableMouseTracking = false,
                                Animation = new Animation(true) { },

                            },
                        })
                        .SetXAxis(new XAxis
                        {
                            Labels = new XAxisLabels
                            {
                                Enabled = false
                            }
                        })
                        .SetYAxis(new YAxis
                        {
                            Title = new YAxisTitle
                            {
                                Text = ""
                            },                                
                            Labels = new YAxisLabels
                            {
                                Enabled = false
                            }

                        })
                        .SetSeries(new[]
                        {
                        new Series
                        {
                            //Name = "ECG1",
                            Data = new Data(chartValues)   // Here we put the dbase data into the chart              
                        },
                    });

            chrtMyChart.Text = chart.ToHtmlString(); // Let's visualize the chart into the webform.
        }
    }
}
```

Y el error que sale al ejecutarlo por medio de un aspx es el siguiente

> Unhandled exception at line 31, column 2 in
>   http://localhost:52255/RevisCurva.aspx
>
> 0x800a01bd - Error en tiempo de ejecución de JavaScript: El objeto no
>   acepta esta acción

¿Cuál puede ser la causa de este error?

```
Chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
        chart: { renderTo:'Chart_container', height: 300, type: 'line', width: 900, zoomType: 'x' }, 
        plotOptions: { line: { animation: true, enableMouseTracking: false } }, 
        title: { text: '' }, 
        xAxis: { labels: { enabled: false } }, 
        yAxis: { labels: { enabled: false }, title: { text: '' } }, 
        series: [{ data: [125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 126, 127, 127, 129, 129, 130, 131, 132, 132, 133, 134, 135, 135, 135, 136, 136, 137, 137, 137, 138, 138, 138, 137, 137, 136, 136, 136, 135, 135, 133, 133, 133, 131, 130, 129, 129, 127, 126, 126, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 7, 1, 0, 16, 24, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 7, 247, 248, 8, 8, 8, 24, 8, 8, 8, 8, 24, 8, 7, 247, 248, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 24, 24, 24, 40, 34, 130, 130, 131, 131, 130, 130, 130, 130, 130, 129, 129, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 127, 127, 128, 128, 128, 127, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 134, 134, 134, 130, 125, 121, 117, 113, 112, 116, 120, 125, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 129, 128, 128, 129, 128, 129, 129, 129, 128, 128, 129, 129, 129, 129, 129, 129, 129, 129, 129, 129, 129, 129, 130, 129, 129, 129, 130, 130, 130, 130, 130, 130, 130, 130, 131, 130, 130, 130, 130, 129, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 129, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 129, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 127, 127, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 126, 127, 127, 129, 129, 130, 131, 132, 132, 133] }]
    });
```

Este es el fragmento de codigo que dice que esta mal con el error

Comment: Por favor coloca el fragmento de código que presenta este error. intenta buscar [0x800a01bd - javascript runtime error object doesn't support this action](https://www.google.com.co/#q=0x800a01bd+-+javascript+runtime+error+object+doesn%27t+support+this+action) y revisa también esta [respuesta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21400123/4092887).

Comment: ya lo agregue..

Answer (score 1):

Si tu pegas el código que te ocasiona problemas en este [enlace](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/basic-line/) y lo ejecutas, verás que el gráfico funciona.

A mi parecer, puede que el `Chart_container` no está disponible cuando ejecutas este código, te sugiero colocar un `setTimeout`.

Ejemplo: `setTimeout(nombre_de_la_funcion, 1000);`

Donde `nombre_de_la_funcion` es la función que contiene tu código.

Ejemplo:

```
function nombre_de_la_funcion() {
  Chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
    chart: { renderTo:'Chart_container', height: 300, type: 'line', width: 900, zoomType: 'x' }, 
    plotOptions: { line: { animation: true, enableMouseTracking: false } }, 
    title: { text: '' }, 
    xAxis: { labels: { enabled: false } }, 
    yAxis: { labels: { enabled: false }, title: { text: '' } }, 
    series: [{ data: [125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 126, 127, 127, 129, 129, 130, 131, 132, 132, 133, 134, 135, 135, 135, 136, 136, 137, 137, 137, 138, 138, 138, 137, 137, 136, 136, 136, 135, 135, 133, 133, 133, 131, 130, 129, 129, 127, 126, 126, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 7, 1, 0, 16, 24, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 7, 247, 248, 8, 8, 8, 24, 8, 8, 8, 8, 24, 8, 7, 247, 248, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 24, 24, 24, 40, 34, 130, 130, 131, 131, 130, 130, 130, 130, 130, 129, 129, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 127, 127, 128, 128, 128, 127, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 134, 134, 134, 130, 125, 121, 117, 113, 112, 116, 120, 125, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 129, 128, 128, 129, 128, 129, 129, 129, 128, 128, 129, 129, 129, 129, 129, 129, 129, 129, 129, 129, 129, 129, 130, 129, 129, 129, 130, 130, 130, 130, 130, 130, 130, 130, 131, 130, 130, 130, 130, 129, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 129, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 129, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 127, 127, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 126, 127, 127, 129, 129, 130, 131, 132, 132, 133] }]
}); 
}
```

Revisa también esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23760181/4092887).