# Cómo colocar nombre en Highcharts

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estoy realizando gráfico de pie chart, también llamado gráfico de pastel, desarrollando en web form asp.net c# con Highcharts .Net, utilizando un `webService` que me extrae un dataSet y lo convierto en un `dataTable`.

Hasta el momento me está saliendo todo bien, el único percance que en vez que salga el nombre de cada sección en el pastel, sale como "Slice". Yo quisiera que en vez de esa palabra se muestra los nombres que están almacenados en mi DataTable.

[image: captura de la gráfica con los nombres incorrectos]

```
DSet = Revi.B_Sp_Rev_IngresarObservaciones(19, Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd").ToString()), Session["username"].ToString(), Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd").ToString()), txtfechainicio.Text, txtfechafin.Text,"","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","");

DSet = Revi.B_Sp_RevCatalogo(74, "", "");

DataTable DT = new DataTable();
DT = DSet.Tables[0];

String[] Browsername = new String[DT.Rows.Count];
String[] Total = new String[DT.Rows.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < DT.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    Browsername[i] = Convert.ToString(DT.Rows[i]["browsername"].ToString());
    Total[i] = Convert.ToString(DT.Rows[i]["total"].ToString());
}

DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts chart = new DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts("chart")
.SetTitle(new DotNet.Highcharts.Options.Title {
    Text = "GRÁFICO PASTEL",
    X = -20
})
.SetSubtitle(new DotNet.Highcharts.Options.Subtitle {
    X = -20
})
.SetXAxis(new DotNet.Highcharts.Options.XAxis {
    Categories = Browsername.ToArray()
})
.SetSeries(new Series {
    Type = ChartTypes.Pie,
    Data = new Data(Total.Select(x => (object)x).ToArray())
});

grafpastelasesor.Text = chart.ToHtmlString();
```

Datos de mi Webservice que me devuelve.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias..!!

Comment: `Data = new Data(Total.Select(x => (object)x).ToArray())` En esta línea, ¿Por qué estás haciendo un casting de `x` a `object`?

Comment: Revisa esto: https://thuru.net/2013/01/06/charting-with-dotnet-highcharts/

Comment: También revisa esta otra pregunta que es muy similar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/23020/822

Comment: @fredyfx muchas gracias :D

Comment: de nada hermano, buenas vibras :D

Comment: @fredyfx lo hice :)

Comment: Me siento muy orgulloso de tus avances mi hermano, aprendes muy rápido, llegarás lejos, sigue elevando ese cosmos con todo el power 2.0!!! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno espero que le ayude resolvi el problema.
lo que pasaba  es la parte de :

```
.SetSeries(new Series {
    Type = ChartTypes.Pie,
    Data = new Data(Total.Select(x => (object)x).ToArray())
});
```

solo mandaba el valor pero no el nombre y como yo tenia en un datatable el valor lo tube que insertar en una lista y colocarle de esta manera.

```
 List<object> studentList = new List<object>();
                for (int i = 0; i < DT.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    studentList.Add(new object[] { DT.Rows[i]["browsername"].ToString(), Convert.ToDecimal(DT.Rows[i]["total"].ToString()) });
                }
```

en la parte de series.

```
 .SetSeries(new Series
                  {
                      Type = ChartTypes.Pie,
                      Name = "Cantidad",
                      Data = new Data(studentList.ToArray())


                  });
```

y asi ya me graficaba y mostraba el valor.

dejo el codigo completo espero que pueda servir a alguien.

```
 Dtset = Rev.B_Sp_RevCatalogo(164, txtfechainicioGO.Text, txtfechafinGO.Text);
                Dtset = Rev.B_Sp_RevCatalogo(165, Session["username"].ToString(), cboagenciaGO.SelectedItem.Value);

                DataTable DT = new DataTable();
                DT = Dtset.Tables[0];

                List<object> studentList = new List<object>();
                for (int i = 0; i < DT.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    studentList.Add(new object[] { DT.Rows[i]["browsername"].ToString(), Convert.ToDecimal(DT.Rows[i]["total"].ToString()) });
                }


                String[] Browsername = new String[DT.Rows.Count];
                String[] Total = new String[DT.Rows.Count];
                for (int i = 0; i < DT.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    Browsername[i] = Convert.ToString(DT.Rows[i]["browsername"].ToString());
                    Total[i] = Convert.ToString(DT.Rows[i]["total"].ToString());
                }

                DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts chart = new DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts("chart")

                .SetTitle(new DotNet.Highcharts.Options.Title
                {
                    Text = "GRÁFICO PASTEL TERRITORIO" ,
                    X = -20
                })
                 .SetSubtitle(new DotNet.Highcharts.Options.Subtitle
                 {

                     X = -20
                 })
                .SetXAxis(new DotNet.Highcharts.Options.XAxis
                {
                    Categories = Browsername.ToArray()

                })

                  .SetSeries(new Series
                  {
                      Type = ChartTypes.Pie,
                      Name = "Cantidad",
                      Data = new Data(studentList.ToArray())
                     // Data = new Data(Total.Select(x => (object)x).ToArray())

                  });


                btngenerargraficoobservacion.Text = chart.ToHtmlString();
```